# Bootstrap Modal adding padding-right to elements with the class "is-fixed"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using an Element component in my application that uses a class called "is-fixed". When I show a Bootstrap modal, any element with "is-fixed" gets injected with an inline style of "padding-right".

How can I tell Bootstrap to stop it?

I currently have added `.is-fixed { padding-right: 5px !important; }`, but this only works for specific cases.

I can't find anything about *Bootstrap and is-fixed* on Google since Google keeps changing my **is-fixed** to **is fixed**...

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community. For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Chrome DevTools in order to inspect that modal element that has class `.is-fixed`. You will then be able to see where does the class come from, just like the example below :
[image: In this example, class <code>.text-muted</code> comes from file _text.scss on line 52]

In this example, class `.text-muted`comes from file _text.scss on line 52.
You will then be able to edit class `.is-fixed` as you want in your own CSS stylesheet, just make sure that this file is loaded after the file where class `.is-fixed` is originally loaded, so that it will have priority over it. You can additionally make your properties `!important`.
Hope that helps.